# How to find the exact time of posting?

Tags: support, timestamps

I just wanted to show somebody that I received an answer a just couple of seconds after posting the question, but the only times I see are "6 hours ago". Another use would be for finding out which answer came first (e.g., as a tie-breaker for accepting).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hover over the "6 hours ago" and you'll get the UTC timestamp in the tooltip.

Comment: great! Those vague time specifications are often annoying...

Comment: Is there any way to do this on mobile? I don’t exactly have a mouse pointer to hover with.