# Exact times of answer posts

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the exact time of posting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78685/how-to-find-the-exact-time-of-posting)

Is there any way, besides a direct database query, to determine which of two identical answers was posted first? I don't suspect either answer to be a copy of the other, but would just like to be fair on which one I accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hover over the "1 minute ago" text (or similar), and it will show you the exact time on a second precision.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Exactly. The exact time *this question was posted* was `2011-08-01 21:12:44Z`

Comment: By the way, is there a way to easily copy+paste this timestamp? (This will depend on browser, I suppose.)

Comment: You can **View/Source**, and search for "post-signature owner"

Comment: @Paulo In chrome you can "inspect element" and copy it from there. So no, not really :)

Comment: @Michael: Ah, the same thing works in Opera, too (and takes not too many clicks at all). Thanks for the idea.